# Why is my characters hand spinning in a circle?

Tags: animation, rigging

I am using Blender 2.8. I have been trying to make a character I just rigged dab (because it is a simple movement), but early in [the video](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ9xvjkZnAfefR46YhXY5zMpTWL0k0clKohk) my character's hand spins 360 degrees along the Y-Axis in the frames between my two keyframes. I have tried rotating the final position 360 degrees in all directions, but the hand is still spinning in a circle. Why, and what could I do to prevent this? [Here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ9xvjkZnAfefR46YhXY5zMpTWL0k0clKohk) is the render. It is a short video, so I couldn't attach it to this post. Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
[Here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZMNjukZLg2UYbPXg88ACgv5FQrmiYmEBs6k) is the *.blend file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made a gif of the fix
[image]

So I'm guessing you made one of the keyframes with a bit too much rotation. Not 100% sure what caused it, but the gif shows a way to fix it. I deleted the last keyframe on the character's right hand and re-made it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error/mistake in the animation part of the blender. I am pretty sure that you have a keyframe with a value like '24' right next to another keyframe with a value of '384' (or some values like that). The keyframes are so close to each other and so different, that when they are played, they make the hand move super fast that way.
To fix this, I would delete the keyframes and remake them with smaller values.

Comment: I only have two keyframes, one at the end, and one at the start.

Comment: Oh! I see now! I was not able to view the video you linked and so I assumed your problem was different. I think If you added in-between frames or even re-key the last frames, then this will be resolved. Some times, it takes a lot of moving the bones to get them in the right place. Some times you could move them too much. Causing the bones to go in full circles. I'm not too sure though. Could you link the .blend here somehow? I do know a lot with animation and I am pretty confident I can find a solution.

Comment: Ok I will put a link to the .blend file. When I tried to put keyframes in between, Since I was rotating the hand myself, it led to some really unnatural, jerky movements.

Comment: I put a link to the *.blend file